# Unable to retrieve the text inside the div tag even when the tag is identified

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to retrieve the text embedded inside the div tag. Partial html code is given below. I consulted the other existing answers, but the tag is located successfully but the text is coming back as empty string.My purpose is to retrieve the string between the 'div' tag as "You entered an invalid username or password, please try again."

I used the `xpath`

```
//div[@class='login-card js-login-card']/div[@role='alert']/div[2]
```

I used the `css`

```
  .alert__heading.js-alert--error-text
```

This only getting back the tag name as div, but the text as an empty string.
Any ideas or corrections?

```
<div class="login-card js-login-card">
  <div class="login-page__alert alert alert--error tt js-alert--error" role="alert">
    <div class="alert__icon">
      <div class="alert__heading js-alert--error-text">You entered an invalid username or password, please try again. </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cmePageWrapper" class="page-wrapper page-wrapper--card"> </div>
```

Comment: can you please show the commnad you are using to get the text?

Comment: List<WebElement> we = wd.findElements(By.xpath("XPath"));
Then
println ("message elements size, tag = "+we.size()+", "+we.get(0).getTagName());
I am getting back 1 and div, but no text string.

Comment: List<WebElement> we = wd.findElements(By.xpath("XPath"));
Then using
println ("message elements size, tag = "+we.size()+", "+we.get(0).getTagName());

I am getting back values as '1' and 'div', but no text string.
This means there is only such 'div' element, but it is unable ot retrieve the text enveloped by it.

Comment: Please add all relevant info to the question itself so that it's easier for everyone to see and properly formatted so it's easier to read.

Comment: Also, in the question you stated that you used CSS but in the code you posted you are using XPath. Please edit the question and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try following **xpath**, as the required **div** tag is child node of **div** with class 'alert__icon':

```
//div[@class='login-card js-login-card']/div[@role='alert']/div[1]/div
```

Let me know, if it works for you.

Comment: List<WebElement> we = wd.findElements(By.xpath("XPath"));
Then using
println ("message elements size, tag = "+we.size()+", "+we.get(0).getTagName());

I am getting back values as '1' and 'div', but no text string.
This means there is only such 'div' element, but it is unable ot retrieve the text enveloped by it.

Comment: Are you sure, you used `xpath` as `//div[@class='login-card js-login-card']/div[@role='alert']/div[1]/div`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanna try this

```
div[class*="error-text"]
```

If it didn't work try to get text by executing javascript code using this

```
$$( "div[class*="error-text"]" ).text()  OR  .val()/.html()
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You could use contains with xpath, something like //div[contains(@class, 'error-text' ) ], using findelement will retrieve first element match the criteria. If it still returns empty, it means that the page might have more than one element which match the criteria

Comment: List<WebElement> we = wd.findElements(By.xpath("XPath"));
 Then using println ("message elements size, tag = "+we.size()+", "+we.get(0).getTagName()); 

I am getting back values as '1' and 'div', but no text string.

This means there is only such 'div' element, but it is unable ot retrieve the text enveloped by it.

Comment: to make sure, you are using element. getText() to get the text right? it will print the inner text of the element.